# redmine link to the heading on the same page

Tags: hyperlink, wiki, redmine

How to create link on the same page to a heading?

I tried following

```
[[#heading1|link text]]
```

but that does not work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your page is `/projects/demo/wiki/testpage`:

```
[[testpage#heading1|link text]]
```

will generate

```
<a class="wiki-page" href="#heading1">link text</a>
```